# Flyway migration not deleting table

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I'm using Flyway with a Spring Boot application, and everything has been working fine until the current migration, which tries to delete a table from the database:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS project_register_maps;
```

In the application log, the migration is marked as successful:

```
2023-06-17 16:14:01.695  INFO 29845 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema `prod` to version "35 - delete project register maps"
2023-06-17 16:14:01.729  INFO 29845 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 1 migration to schema `prod`, now at version v35 (execution time 00:00.052s)
```

But when looking at the database tables after the migration, it seems that the table I wanted to delete is still there:

```
mysql> show tables;
+--------------------------------+
| Tables_in_prod                 |
+--------------------------------+
| ...                            |
| flyway_schema_history          |
| project_register_maps          |
| ...                            |
+--------------------------------+
```

Another suspect thing is that the checksum of the script equals zero--that's an unlikely value for a checksum:

```
mysql> select * from flyway_schema_history where installed_rank = 35;
+----------------+---------+------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+
| installed_rank | version | description                  | type | script                                | checksum | installed_by | installed_on        | execution_time | success |
+----------------+---------+------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+
|             35 | 35      | delete project register maps | SQL  | V35__delete_project_register_maps.sql |        0 | root         | 2023-06-17 14:14:01 |              7 |       1 |
+----------------+---------+------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Are you running this code locally? Is the flyway configuration pointing to the correct file?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your .properties files if the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto variable is set to 'none'. If it is set to 'update' and you have not yet removed the model class or at least its @Entity annotation, Flyway will execute the migration to drop the table, but JPA will recreate it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on this checksum = 0. The checksum is calculated based on the contents of the migration script. The fact that the checksum is 0 could mean that the script file is empty or that it contains only whitespace characters.

The migration being empty would justify its success.

Check whether the flyway configuration is pointing to the correct file or that the file was committed correctly to the repo.